# Is it possible to connect android phone to printer via bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, printing, wireless

I know that android sdk 2.0 has provided the new [bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) for developers. But I'm not sure if this can help me connect to bluetooth printers. Are there any protocol restrictions or device limitaion for this? Is it possible that the bluetooth device is undetectable by android phone?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think BPP is a protocol that is inherently supported to the android implementation of bluetooth. The [Sybase iAnywhere Blue SDK](http://www.sybase.com/files/Data_Sheets/Sybase_SiA_Android_DS.pdf) ([2](http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/mobiledevicesdks/bluetoothsdks)) looks to be a way that you can implement it within custom applications.

Answer (score 0):

BPP UUID is `00001120-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`. I have a feeling it might be possible by connecting to the BPP UUID using Android's RFCOMM method calls.