# What are my options for printing from android?

Tags: android, printing, usb

Mobile devices/tablets have usb ports so is there a way to send the print job directly via USB if connected to the printer?

Also, is it an ok solution in terms of simplicity and reliability to have the android device to create a 2d graphic of text, upload it to an application server via wifi, notify a desktop with a printer to do the job with the graphic.

Someone suggested to me to use a wireless (wifi) printer but really I need to set this up for a thermal printer to print receipts from my app.

If there are other better methods please share them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found out that STAR Micronics support android printing on certain models (there are quite a few models supported).

STAR give you the option of using the WiFi or Bluetooth to connect, I think Ethernet is also supported but you have to have certain  models of the Ethernet adapter inserts that plug into the back of your thermal printer.

Here is the link:
http://www.star-m.jp/eng/dl/dl02_06_02spsd.htm

The reason this is so difficult to find is that it is not listed on the other star micronics websites (only this japanese one) and you have to manually go to the Downloads section to see it.

In case the link gets broken the Android SDK you want is called:
StarIO_Android_V1000a

If you do a google search you should find it.

Comment: @Lisa you should've commented this here but thanks. http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Comment: Wanted to but not enough rep at that time. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the options for printing from the Android Device.

**Thermal Printers -** In market no of thermal printer are available like EPSON, Casio, STAR or Chinese printers. These printers have their own SDK. By simply import that sdk in project you can print from the application.

**Connectivity** is the main thing in using those printers. Every user have different kind of needs. So we can connect with thermal printers via **USB, Bluetooth, WiFi, COM Port 232, Ethernet.**

Also one more thing is you can *install your printer drivers and CUPS on Server* and directly send the printing request to the server and server send it to printer IP. This feature allow you to print form anywhere no issue of slow connection like we face in BT and WiFi.

**Google Cloud Printers -** In this case you have to registered your printer on Google printers and through Google Cloud printer API's we can print from the Android Device.

My personal opinion is to go for the Thermal printer as i have used the EPSON, Casio and some other and they are fairly easy to use and satisfy all our needs.

For the Developers here is one sample how to deal with thermal printer

[How to print from the Thermal Printer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701465/how-to-print-from-the-thermal-printer-in-android)

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have two main approaches:

1. Google Cloud print system -> but there is no thermal printer that supports the protocol so the printer must be connected to some computer (win/mac)
2. Try to use some bluetooth thermal printer as discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135673/android-bluetooth-printer).

Personally, I think the best way is doing by bluetooth printer...

Comment: Thanks for that.. didn't know about bluetooth printers... so how about this Zebra company, have you used their sdk and are their printers any good?

Comment: No, I just searched a bit about the subject. Sorry I cannot help more

Answer (score 2):

The link posted above to the Japanese site is broken. The latest version of the Star Android printer SDK can be found here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A lan/wifi printer should work.However you should handle data flow.If you have a desktop app then things change.Do you have a desktop app or not?

Comment: No actually trying to avoid the reliance on a desktop for minimal system cost. it would have been a last resort so im more interested in the bluetooth option right now

Comment: i dont know whether bluetooth is going to work. It should be within max 10 meters not so good alternative..

Comment: in which situation is a receipt printer not within 10 metres of a terminal? :P